# single sql connection over multiple web pages

Tags: html, sql, vbscript, asp-classic

How is it possible to use sql connection string over multiple web pages. I've been looking at the code below but i cant see how the code connects to the database.

select case str_Action

```
case str_AddLangText
    ' Complete add
    if isarray(str_temp1) and isarray(lng_ActionPermissionID) then
        for lng_Count2 = lbound(lng_ActionPermissionID) to ubound(lng_ActionPermissionID)
            if isnumeric(lng_ActionPermissionID(lng_Count2)) then
                for lng_Count = lbound(str_temp1, 2) to ubound(str_temp1, 2)
                    str_SQL = "A_PagePermission_insert"
                    obj_ADO.ClearParameters
                    obj_ADO.AddParameter "SessionID", adChar, adParamInput, len(obj_Session.str_SessionID), obj_Session.str_SessionID
                    obj_ADO.AddParameter "PermissionID", adInteger, adParamInput, 8, clng(lng_ActionPermissionID(lng_Count2))                       
                    obj_ADO.AddParameter "PageID", adInteger, adParamInput, 8, clng(str_temp1(0, lng_Count))
                    obj_ADO.Execute str_SQL, adCmdStoredProc, obj_Session.int_CommandTimeout & "<br />"
                next
            end if
        next
    else
        str_Messages = trim(obj_Content.GetContent("ErrorCode50003"))
    end if
    str_Action = obj_Session.str_FileName
case str_DeleteLangText
    'Complete delete
    if isarray(str_temp1) and isnumeric(lng_PermissionID) then
        for lng_Count = lbound(str_temp1, 2) to ubound(str_temp1, 2)
            str_SQL = "A_PagePermission_delete"
            obj_ADO.ClearParameters
            obj_ADO.AddParameter "SessionID", adChar, adParamInput, len(obj_Session.str_SessionID), obj_Session.str_SessionID
            obj_ADO.AddParameter "PermissionID", adInteger, adParamInput, 8, clng(lng_PermissionID)
            obj_ADO.AddParameter "PageID", adInteger, adParamInput, 8, str_temp1(0, lng_Count)
            obj_ADO.Execute str_SQL, adCmdStoredProc, obj_Session.int_CommandTimeout & "<br />"
        next
    else
        str_Messages = trim(obj_Content.GetContent("ErrorCode50056"))
    end if
    str_Action = obj_Session.str_FileName
case else
```

end select 
str_Messages = str_Messages & "
" & vbcrlf & str_Required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj_ADO` is probably instantiated in previous code blocks. Have you checked if your code files all include the same file (usually conn.asp, setup.asp or similar)?

Do a "Find in files" search with `obj_ADO`. You should be able to find where it is being used.

**Edit**

If you get too many results with that, try searching for `Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")` or some other variant of ADODB.